# Need help querying top reddit comments by top posts

Tags: google-bigquery, reddit

I'm trying to collect the (let's say top 20) most upvoted comments within the most upvoted posts of a given subreddit.

Any help would be appreciated!

I've gotten to this code which I use in bigquery, but I can't seem to get the post score and the comment score without a duplicate issue.

```
SELECT posts.title, posts.score, comments.body, posts.subreddit
FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2018_10` AS comments
JOIN `fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2018_10`  AS posts
ON posts.id = SUBSTR(comments.link_id, 4) 
WHERE posts.subreddit = 'Showerthoughts'
```

For a simplified example I would like to be able to see:

> Post Title 1 | Post Score | (Within Post Title 1) Comment Body 1 |
>   Comment Score
>
> Post Title 1 | Post Score | (Within Post Title 1) Comment Body 2 |
>   Comment Score
>
> Post Title 2 | Post Score | (Within Post Title 2) Comment Body 1 |
>   Comment Score
>
> Post Title 2 | Post Score | (Within Post Title 2) Comment Body 2 |
>   Comment Score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick way of getting around the issue of duplicate text blobs:

```
select title, score, body, subreddit from (
    SELECT 
        to_hex(md5(posts.title)), 
        array_agg(posts.title)[offset(0)] as title, 
        array_agg(comments.body)[offset(0)] as body, 
        array_agg(posts.score)[offset(0)] as score, 
        array_agg(posts.subreddit)[offset(0)] as subreddit
    FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2018_10` AS comments
    JOIN `fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2018_10`  AS posts
    ON posts.id = SUBSTR(comments.link_id, 4) 
    WHERE posts.subreddit = 'Showerthoughts'
    group by 1
    order by 1
)
```

The idea is to convert that expensive text blob into a md5 hash, and then going about your usual business with the unique entries. You can sort stuff the way you want out of these distinct values.

Comment: Thanks! If you don't mind, I ran into another issue. This query is huge because it collects all the posts and all the comments of the subreddit.  Would this work to limit the retrieved posts to just ones with significant upvotes? WHERE posts.subreddit = 'Showerthoughts' AND posts.score >1000 AND comments.score >1000